# R code coverage for the testthat package

Tags: r, testing, code-coverage

Is there any tools to evaluate code coverage for R scripts using the `testthat` package? I found nothing by Google except a mention of the topic in the *Future work* section of [an RJournal article](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-1/RJournal_2011-1_Wickham.pdf).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The I'll answer my own question :-)

I asked the same question at the project site. **It seems at the moment there is no such support for the *testthat* library**, but the possibility recently opened by using the development version of R and exploiting some new features of the profiler. Unfortunately, it seems a huge work to do that, but hopefully someone will take the lead on that.

Find the details [in this ticket](https://github.com/hadley/test_that/issues/45#issuecomment-8438700).

Comment: It seems this answer is kind of obsolete now; see my answer.

Answer (score 25):

There is the newly-arrived [`covr` package](https://github.com/jimhester/covr) which seems to do everything you want, and more! It provides integration with various CI services and shiny. It works with any kind of testing infrastructure (testthat, RUnit, anything else) and also works with compiled code.

---

What follows is just a very simple demo case I compiled quickly to get you started.

```
install.packages("covr")
```

Add a file `testcovr/R/doublefun.r` containing

```
doublefun <- function(x, superfluous_option) {
    if (superfluous_option) {
        2*x
    } else {
        3*x
    }
}
```

and a file `testcovr/tests/testthat/test.doublefun.r` containing

```
context("doublefun")

test_that("doublefun doubles correctly", {

    expect_equal(doublefun(1, TRUE), 2)
})
```

and then run e.g.

```
test("testcovr")
## Testing testcovr
## doublefun : .

library(covr)
package_coverage("testcovr")
## doublefun : .
##
## Package Coverage: 66.67%
## R/doublefun.r: 66.67%
zero_coverage(package_coverage("testcovr"))
## doublefun : .
##
##        filename first_line last_line first_column last_column value
## 3 R/doublefun.r          5         5            9          11     0
```

Comment: The testthat package itself uses covr to measure code coverage. This is visible in testthat's [travis.yml file](https://github.com/hadley/testthat/blob/24d76a1ed7b018440dd91450fce8a02420480955/.travis.yml).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt at calculating test coverage for a set of R files at the function level:

https://gist.github.com/cannin/819e73426b4ebd5752d5

It depends on using regular expressions to find where functions are created and when they are called.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution to evaluate code coverage for R scripts using the `testthat` package:

```
library(covr)
coverage_to_list()
```